# Weird capabilities / roles behavior

Tags: custom-post-types, capabilities, user-roles

I've been playing with the custom post types capabilities and some behaviors remains really mysticals for me.

## The Setup

Say you have a Custom Post Type (CPT) called **show** for defining a radio broadcast with this capabilities :

```
'capabilities' => array(

    // meta caps
    'read_post'                 => 'read_show',
    'edit_post'                 => 'edit_show',
    'delete_post'               => 'delete_show',

    // primitive/meta caps
    'create_posts'              => 'create_shows',

    // primitive caps used outside of map_meta_cap()
    'publish_posts'             => 'publish_shows',
    'read_private_posts'        => 'read_private_shows',
    'edit_posts'                => 'edit_shows',
    'edit_others_posts'         => 'edit_others_shows',

    // primitive caps used inside of map_meta_cap()
    'read'                      => 'read_shows',
    'edit_private_posts'        => 'edit_private_shows',
    'edit_published_posts'      => 'edit_published_shows',
    'delete_posts'              => 'delete_shows',
    'delete_private_posts'      => 'delete_private_shows',
    'delete_published_posts'    => 'delete_published_shows',
    'delete_others_posts'       => 'delete_others_shows'

)
```

Add another CPT called **podcast** which are linked to a radio broadcast via a meta value (anyway, it's not important here). It ha these capabilities :

```
'capabilities'          => array(

    // meta caps
    'read_post'                 => 'read_podcast',
    'edit_post'                 => 'edit_podcast',
    'delete_post'               => 'delete_podcast',

    // primitive/meta caps
    'create_posts'              => 'create_podcasts',

    // primitive caps used outside of map_meta_cap()
    'publish_posts'             => 'publish_podcasts',
    'read_private_posts'        => 'read_private_podcasts',
    'edit_posts'                => 'edit_podcasts',
    'edit_others_posts'         => 'edit_others_podcasts',

    // primitive caps used inside of map_meta_cap()
    'read'                      => 'read_podcasts',
    'edit_private_posts'        => 'edit_private_podcasts',
    'edit_published_posts'      => 'edit_published_podcasts',
    'delete_posts'              => 'delete_podcasts',
    'delete_private_posts'      => 'delete_private_podcasts',
    'delete_published_posts'    => 'delete_published_podcasts',
    'delete_others_posts'       => 'delete_others_podcasts'

)
```

Say you add a new role called **Show Runner** which should have this rights :

- **Edit** its own radio broadcast (no creation or deletion, the radio broadcast is created by an editor which change the author to the show runner).
- **Create / Edit** its podcasts (but not publish or delete)

Here is the role capabilities mapping :

```
add_role(
    'show_runner',
    __( 'Show Runner', 'lang_plugin' ),
    array(
        'read'                          => true,
        /* Media upload */
        'upload_files'                  => true,
        /* CPT show */
        'read_shows'                    => true,
        'create_shows'                  => false,
        'publish_shows'                 => false,
        'edit_shows'                    => true,
        'edit_published_shows'          => true,
        'delete_shows'                  => false,
        /* CPT podcast */
        'read_podcasts'                 => true,
        'create_podcasts'               => true,
        'publish_podcasts'              => false,
        'edit_podcasts'                 => true,
        'edit_published_podcasts'       => true,
        'delete_podcasts'               => false,
    )
);
```

## The first weird thing

A show runner can **not** access the list of shows although he has 'read_shows' and 'edit_shows' to true and that I can see the "Shows" Menu in the sidebar.

But if I put 'create_shows' to true, he access the list...and can create a show (but I don't want that !).

## The second weird thing (coming from the first one)

I have set 'create_shows' to false (to reflect what I really want) again before continuing.

If I change the **show_in_menu** parameters of the **podcast** CPT to put it into the **show** menu (as a submenu) like this :

```
'show_in_menu'          => 'edit.php?post_type=show'
```

... then the show runner has access to the Shows list, without the "New Show" button. Cool ! That's what I want.

**BUT** : If the show runner tries to create a new podcast (he can do this regarding capabilities), wordpress says he has no rights for this...

## Conclusion / Question

Why a CPT creation depends like this of the menu position ?? It's like the podcast CPT heritates of the *false* value of *create_shows* although it's *true* for him.

Subquestion : how can a role have access to the list of a CPT without setting 'create_xxxxx' to *true* ?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like [core bug #22895](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22895).

Access to the menu item will not be allowed unless the user also has the `edit_posts` capability (for the `Post` post type).

Comment: wow. It looks like it's a deep one... there is plenty of other long time bugs linked to it... Do you think I should post a new bug to see if core developers link this to other bugs ?